# Using reindex with duplicated axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe with dates as index. Each row contains information about a certain event on that date. The problem is that there could be more than one event on said date.
This is an example DataFrame, df2:

```
     one  two
1/2  1.0  1.0
1/2  1.0  1.0
1/4  3.0  3.0
1/5  NaN  4.0
```

I want to add missing dates to the dataframe, and I used to be able to do it with .loc. Now .loc raises the following warning:

> Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
>   KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.

This is my code (it works but raises warning):

```
# I want to add any missing date- in this example, 1/3.
df2.loc[["1/2","1/3","1/4","1/5"]]

     one  two
1/2  1.0  1.0
1/2  1.0  1.0
1/3  NaN  NaN
1/4  3.0  3.0
1/5  NaN  4.0
```

I've tried using reindex as it suggests, but my index contains duplicated values so it doesn't work:

```
#This doesn't work
df2.reindex(["1/2","1/3","1/4","1/5"])
```

> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

What can I do to replace the old loc?

Comment: Just curious why you need duplicated index here...

Comment: I could probably add "date" as a column (instead of an index)  and use .reset_index() to generate a new index. It's an old piece of code and .loc didn't raise a warning before updating to pandas 0.22

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way from `join`

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame(index=["1/2","1/3","1/4","1/5"]),how='outer')
Out[193]: 
     one  two
1/2  1.0  1.0
1/2  1.0  1.0
1/3  NaN  NaN
1/4  3.0  3.0
1/5  NaN  4.0
```